# How to broadcast Objects across executors in Spark scala?

Tags: apache-spark, broadcast, executors

I am sure we can broadcast the values of variables but i am not sure how to broadcast an object created in driver across executors. I am creating an object for a third party Java class in my Scala program. I want to share the same instance of the class to all executors instead of creating multiple objects.

I found that broadcast method can be used for broadcasting the values of variables. But i do not know if that can be used for broadcasting objects. Please post your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

With broadcast you can broadcast objects as well. See the API for broadcast

```
broadcast[T](value: T)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[T]): Broadcast[T]
Broadcast a read-only variable to the cluster, returning a     org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast object for reading it in distributed functions.
```

broadcast variables are supposed to be read only so you should have to worry about it being the same instance or a different one.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if there is a difference between "values" and "objects". Also I didn't think that on a distributed system you can share a "same instance of the class", as each JVM will have its own instance.